# Python Pandas groupby with agg() nth() and/or iloc()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

Given this DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B'] 
                  , 'Col2':['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
                  , 'Col3':['Apple', 'Peach', 'Apricot', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse', 'Horse']
                  ,})

df
```

And then using this code:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Col1').agg({'Col2':'count', 'Col3': lambda x: x.iloc[2]})
df1
```

I got this result:

[image]

**What I would like now:**

Being able to make the lambda function `'Col3': lambda x: x.iloc[0]` to `print('Not enough data')` when dealing with error for example if I change "**x.iloc[0]**" to "**x.iloc[3]**" which raised an error because there's not enough data in "**Col1['A']** compared to "**Col1['B']**".

**!! Don't want to use 'last' because this is a simplified and shortened DF for purpose !!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) that will give you a NaN if the value is missing. Unfortunately, `nth` is not handled by `agg` so you need to compute it separately and join:

```
g = df.groupby('Col1')
df1 = g.agg({'Col2':'count'}).join(g['Col3'].nth(3))
```

output:

```
      Col2   Col3
Col1             
A        3    NaN
B        4  Horse
```

Comment: Thank you, actually i was trying to use nth() INSIDE the agg() but didn't seem to work, any idea why?

Comment: @drakax I just added a comment on that, unfortunately `nth` doesn't work with `agg`… (it is not a Series method)

Comment: Ok., thank you again. 2 more things please, any way to make nth() print something instead of returning NaN? And how do you copy/paste dataframe like your outpout in stackoverflow?

Comment: Use `g['Col3'].nth(3).fillna('Not enough data')`. To copy/paste, simply use `print(df1)` and copy/paste in between triple backticks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a slice object which will return empty Series if none value.

```py
df1 = df.groupby('Col1').agg({'Col2':'count',
                              'Col3': lambda x: x.iloc[3:4] if len(x.iloc[3:4]) else pd.NA})
```

```
print(df1)

      Col2   Col3
Col1
A        3   <NA>
B        4  Horse
```

You can save typing with named expression if your Python version is greater than 3.8

```py
df1 = df.groupby('Col1').agg({'Col2':'count',
                              'Col3': lambda x: v if len(v := x.iloc[3:4]) else pd.NA})
```

Comment: Thank you too! Nice lambda alternative, could use it for further cases :)

Comment: any idea why I can't use an integer with your iloc[] solution? If I write x.iloc[3] or x.iloc[[3]] instead of x.iloc[3:4], it raises an the following error "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds." If I use iloc[] outside the lambda function, df.iloc[0] == df.iloc[0:1], what am I missing?

Comment: @drakax `iloc` will throw error if index out of bounds but it wouldn't with slice object.